# Getting error while starting GeoServer after GeoMesa installation

Tags: geoserver, geomesa

I'm trying to install GeoMesa and GeoServer. After completing the GeoMesa installation process / steps given at http://www.geomesa.org/documentation/user/installation_and_configuration.html.
I have tried to start GeoServer, but I am getting the following error:

```
hduser@ram-VPCEB3AGG:/usr/local/geoserver$ bin/startup.sh 
GEOSERVER DATA DIR is /usr/local/geoserver/data_dir
2016-02-26 15:03:35.061::INFO:  Logging to STDERR via org.mortbay.log.StdErrLog
2016-02-26 15:03:35.108::WARN:  Deprecated configuration used for /usr/local/geoserver/webapps
2016-02-26 15:03:35.133::INFO:  jetty-6.1.8
2016-02-26 15:03:36.129::WARN:  Failed startup of context org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext@142bad79{/geoserver,file:/usr/local/geoserver/webapps/geoserver/}
java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:215)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:145)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:154)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:118)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.TagLibConfiguration.configureWebApp(TagLibConfiguration.java:168)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1217)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:510)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:448)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:156)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:222)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
    at org.mortbay.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:977)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.mortbay.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:183)
    at org.mortbay.start.Main.start(Main.java:497)
    at org.mortbay.start.Main.main(Main.java:115)
2016-02-26 15:03:36.137::INFO:  Opened /usr/local/geoserver/logs/2016_02_26.request.log
2016-02-26 15:03:36.153::INFO:  Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8080
```

Comment: finally solve this issue. its because of hdfs and dfs both xml file located into same location...

Comment: Great to hear that you’ve solved your issue! Can you please move your solution into an answer and [accept it](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/) so that this question is marked as closed? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because  **hbase-shaded-client-1.4.11.jar** and
**htrace-core-3.1.0-incubating.jar** are not really jar files. They are Xml files generated due to maven redirects.The **install install-shaded-hbase-hadoop.sh** script is not able to properly download the required jars. Placing the jars manually in WEB-INF/lib directory of the geoserver worked for me. Following are the links for the jars.

- [hbase-shaded-client-1.4.11.jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hbase/hbase-shaded-client/1.4.11)
- [htrace-core-3.1.0-incubating.jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.htrace/htrace-core/3.1.0-incubating)